# Error when outputting assets from a field within a Neo field

Tags: assets, assetfilemodel, plugin-neo

Anyone with Neo experience had issues with outputting an assets field with multiple images?
I am not using a dynamic field, as I saw there are issues with that.

Code

```
{% for asset in block.serviceGallery %}
    <div class="fg-col-xs-6 fg-col-md-4" data-gallery="{{ loop.parent.index }}">
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('square') }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Error:
`Key "index" for array with keys "entry, ... " does not exist.`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reference the field handle within *asset*.
For instance > `{{ asset.imageHandle.getUrl('square') }}`.
I'm guessing you aren't seeing `{{ asset.title }}` either?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was not to do with NEO or how to access them, it was the loop index call to the parent not getting the correct context.

`{{ loop.parent.index }}` was the issue. It needed to be `{{ loop.parent.loop.parent.loop.index }}`